# CSS Hover effect on child element inside svg object

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to apply a css fill color to an svg object on the hover event of it's parent `<a>` element.

On non-svg elements, this would work:

```
.icon {
    background-color: #000;
}

a:hover .icon {
    background-color: #666
}
```

But when using an svg object where the svg file has the class .icon applied to the `<svg>` element...

```
<a href="#">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="icon.svg"></object>
</a>
```

It doesn't work.

```
.icon {
    fill: #000;
}

a:hover .icon {
    fill: #666
}
```

The black fill is applied, but the hover won't work. If I apply the fill directly to .icon:hover, it works, but the `<a>` is larger than the icon and has other elements, so if the link is being hovered over, the icon isn't necessarily hovered.

Comment: There is no element with a class of icon in your listed HTML...JSfiddle please.

Comment: The <svg> element is in a different document and styles don't apply cross-document. You could make the SVG inline or move the hover styles into the SVG document itself. Linking i.e. putting an `<a>` round an `<object>` shouldn't work if the content is interactive (and SVG is that) so the link itself shouldn't work although I understand that some UAs incorrectly allow this.

Comment: the class="icon" is in the icon.svg file. and is working correctly because the black fill can be applied. I'll provide a link to JSfiddle shortly.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/links-inline-svg-staying-target-events/

Comment: Here's a link to a JSfiddle where the svg is included inline: http://jsfiddle.net/QMuc6/

Comment: It works here, but inline svg doesn't allow for caching, so I wanted to use an object to fix this and clean up the document a bit.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/